# Which drivers should I install?

Tags: drivers, ati, dell, fglrx, catalyst

i'm currently using Catalyst 13.4 on Dell 1749 i3 (GPU: ATI5650) but last time I saw in the window of "Sotware and Updates", that there are new:

[image]

I checked them out.

I used early Catalyst 13.4 and they weren't bad, but I would like to have newest drivers. So, which driver should i use?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do.

- The most stable driver, and the one that probably gives the best desktop experience is of course the X.Org driver. It has rather bad gaming performance and at least on 12.04 does not support hardware video decoding.
- For gaming the fglrx drivers are usually more performant, also the power consumption is lower than with X.Org drivers. They also enable hardware video decoding (with software that supports it) and OpenCL GPGPU computing.

Now to the different fglrx versions:

- The fglrx package contains the version of fglrx that was available when your installed Ubuntu version was released. If you install this and it works, you can be sure, that it will not be broken by updates.
- fglrx-updates contains updated stable releases of fglrx (usually not the latest, but newer than fglrx). It will be updated from time to time and these updates might break compatibility with your hardware or introduce new bugs. Nevertheless, it's also expected to be more performant than fglrx
- The experimental packages contain beta drivers. There is a rather high chance that they will not work or introduce new bugs, but they are probably again a bit faster. At least on 12.04 they are not compatible with hardware video decoding and do not come with OpenCL libraries.